# Dynamically added rows, setOnClickListener TextView

Tags: android, linker, onclick, textview, rows

I have a for loop that each time prints out a row with a TextView within. I want this TextView to be clickable, and when clicked it is supposed to start another activity and send an ID with the Intent. But it's this that I can't manage to work. All links shows up nicely in a table and the textviews are clickable, but all links sends me to the next activity with the same ID, the ID of the last link.

Here is a simplified version of the content of the for loop:

```
TextView title = new TextView(this);
title.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
title.setText(titleLine);
title.setClickable(true);
title.setId(rows);
rows++;

title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(a.this, b.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("id", idLine);
        a.this.startActivity(myIntent);
    }
});

contRight.addView(title);
```

I suppose the problem is that all textViews looks the same, so the last setOnClickListener works on all links. However, I have added an ID to each title, with this code: *title.setId(rows);*, so they are all supposed to be unique.

Anybody who can give some help? :) Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shouldn't `idLine` be `v.getId()`? It's good for this value to be as "fresh" as possible so that you aren't reading an old value: in this case, the value of the last row which had probably been lurking in `idLine`. Hence, getting the value from the view directly is the safest method.

Also, the "tag" might be a better place to store information than the id. You can access the tag, and indeed store any number of arguments as tags on any view, without changing the id:

```
title.setTag(rows);
```

and then later:

```
intent.putExtra((Integer) v.getTag());
```

To store multiple objects (with keys) you can use:

```
title.setTag("rowid", rows);
```

and then retrieve it using:

```
intent.putExtra((Integer) v.getTag("rowid"));
```

and then you could add additional keys if you requirements changed.

In any case, the *intention* of the tag is to store information for later retrieval, whereas the id is meant to serve as an identifier for finding views in a hierarchy.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I was totally thinking in the wrong way. idLine was supposed to be v.getId yes. So when I changed it, it worked out smoothly. =)